# backspace issue on linux file

Tags: linux, bash, editplus

I use EditPlus to write linux bash programs. after writting when i move files to server i get these kind of errors:

```
sleep: invalid time interval `2\r'
Try `sleep --help' for more information.

/usr/bin/program: line 9: $'\r': command not found
/usr/bin/program: line 10: $'}\r': command not found
/usr/bin/program: line 11: $'\r': command not found
/usr/bin/program: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'usr/bin/program: line 12: `stop() {
```

I have also used dos2unix to fix this issue but no success. I want to know that is there any way that I can avoid this kind of problems. it waste alot of time. is there any better editor or some way to fix this issue?

EDIT:

What I do to solve this issue is that I vi a file in linux and then copy line by line from windows file to linux file and then it works. these are lines of my code:

line7:udevadm control --reload-rules
        sleep 2
        echo
        echo $(date +"%b %e %T") `hostname` Program[$$]: Program Started | tee -a /var/log/messages
        echo
    }
    stop() {

Comment: I've never used EditPlus before, but [Wikipedia claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EditPlus) that it has a line-ending converter built in.  Have you looked for one?

Comment: consider editing your post to include lines 9-12 of the script that is causing problems. That sure looks like a `dos2unix` solvable problem. Also, use `cat -vet file` to see ctrl-chars embedded in your script. You shouldn't see anything like ^A-^Z in the file. Good luck.

Comment: Btw.: That isn't a backspace, but the carriage-return (alias: return, hence \r) from the CR-LF combo. Backspace would be \b.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to change file preferences: go to Preferences -> Files and change "Create new file as " to UNIX. Also, your might want to enable "Check invalid CR/LF, null character when loading" option.

Answer (score 4):

For already produced files

```
cat OLDFILE | tr -d '\r' > NEWFILE
```

should help. You can't just redirect the output to the input:

```
cat FILE | tr -d '\r' > FILE
```

since this will truncate the input file before it is read.

In contrast to similar programs, this is not eligible for the useless-use-of-cat award, since `tr` doesn't accept a filename as parameter.

Comment: Actually, it is a useless-use-of-cat, since you can just use `tr -d '\r' <OLDFILE >NEWFILE`

Answer (score 3):

Setting the "line ending sequence" in VSCode / atom from CRLF TO LF and saving worked for me