# problems scripting in linux over ssh from mac

Tags: bash, terminal, nano

I have a problem using nano in a server throught ssh from mac or other linux.
If I write 'sleep 10' in the terminal, over ssh, it works.
if I do 'echo "sleep 10" > test.sh' and sh test.sh, it works.
If I open nano, write 'sleep 10' and save as test.sh and do 'sh test.sh' doesnt works saying that 10\r invalid time interval.

Any ideas?

thx an advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [backspace issue on linux file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454309/backspace-issue-on-linux-file)

Comment: `sed -i.bak $'s/\r//' test.sh` Then try SSH.

Answer (score 0):

It smells like the file you are editing already had \r (which is also known as CR or ^M) at the ends of some of it's lines

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' test.sh
```

will cure that.